# Как создать SSL соединение к postgresql из Java swing?

Tags: java

Как создать SSL соединение к postgresql из Java swing?

Answer (score 2):

Надо к jdbc url добавить параметр `ssl=true`.

Comment: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html